# ¿Como hacer para definir un titulo diferente para cada pantalla en Android Studio 2.3.3?

Tags: android-studio

hace poco compre una aplicacion, y estoy modificandolo aun, pero no logro hacer el cambio del titulo del action bar (no del principal, sino para cada pantalla).

Estoy tratando de cambiar el titulo del action bar para cada actividad (facebook, video, fotos, etc), es decir, quiero que el usuario al entrar al apartado de fotos el action bar cambie del titulo principal al titulo de dicha actividad (fotos).

No se si me explico, soy novato en todo esto. 
[image: dejo una captura de lo que quiero hacer]
Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Intenta poner el código que hayas probado para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 3):

Primero create el recurso string para el nombre de la actividad en values/strings.xml

Por ejemplo:

```
<string name="mi_titulo">Mi actividad</string>
```

Puedes cambiar el título desde código java, es decir, dinámicamente o desde el manifest:

**Desde código java**

```
public class MiActividad extends AppCompatActivity {

    String titulo= "mi_actividad";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.setTitle(R.string.mi_titulo);

    }
}
```

**Desde el Manifest**

En el manifest, localizas la actividad cuyo título quieres cambiar y le añades el atributo label con el nuevo valor:

```
<activity android:name=".tu_actividad"
            android:label="@string/mi_titulo"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción y la recomendada por Google en sus videos de entrenamiento es:

1. Crear el recurso string tal como ya se mencionó (en la ruta app/res/values/strings.xml)
2. Agregar en el archivo AndroidManifest.xml (en la ruta app/manifests) dentro de la actividad específica, por ejemplo, el atributo android:label="@string/numbers_activity_name".

Por ejemplo, en el AndroidManifest.xml podría quedar algo así:

```
<activity
    android:name=".NumbersActivity"
    android:exported="false"
    android:label="@string/numbers_activity_name" />
```